# SOQL to extract all fields details of an Object

Tags: apex, soql

I need to extract all the field definitions of some of the Objects from Salesforce. Is it possible with SOQl or simple apex which I can run in Anonymous Apex window. I don't have much time to write a Class and migrate code to PROD. So if there is a straight forward approach, please let me know or else I need to copy paste manually.

Comment: What do you plan to do with this info? I can think of several choices.

Comment: We have master data implementation team who wants to map Salesforce table and columns with their Informatica tables & columns. I need to provide Salesforce object and field api details.

Comment: You can use [Field Trip](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003HSXEEA4), a free app that will scan your data and put it into a nice format you can report on/export. You could, of course, write your own code, but if you're in a hurry, this will get it done.

Comment: Thank you very much for immediate reply. I am installing now. Will let you know how it goes.

Comment: @sfdcfox - This app really helped me. Please add it as an answer so I could mark as Best answer. Thank you very much. Only drawback with that app is, it doesn't provide length/size of the Fields.

Comment: Sure thing. If you have a developer handy, they could add some code/fields to get the length values as well, if you wanted to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Field Trip](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003HSXEEA4) app, a free product on the AppExchange, to create a list of your objects and fields, including things like their data type. You'll be able to report on these objects and export them for your purposes.